# Show that $\frac{B(x,y)}{c^{y}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(c+t)}^{x+y}}$

Tags: integration, special-functions

I have to show the followiing equation, but I can't see how that can even be true:

$$\frac{B(x,y)}{c^{y}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(c+t)}^{x+y}}$$

What I tried is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(1+t)}^{x+y}c^{y}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(1+t)}^{x}{(1+t)}^{y}c^{y}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(1+t)}^{x}{(c+ct)}^{y}}$$
but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere since it doesn't result in the integral on the right side.

Comment: Yeah it does thanks! Do you know how I get the equality $B(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{y}B(x,y+1)$ taking the derivative of the upper equation with respect to c?

Comment: I've added below since there is more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$c^{-y}B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(c+t)^{-x-y}t^{x-1}dt \space\space(\dagger)$$

Differentiating wrt to $c$ we obtain (when we have uniform convergence)
$$-yc^{-y-1}B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(-x-y)(c+t)^{-x-y-1}t^{x-1}dt$$
$$=-(x+y)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(c+t)^{x+(y+1)}}\space\space(\star)$$

But we know from $(\dagger)$ that $$c^{-(y+1)}B(x,y+1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(c+t)^{x+(y+1)}}dt$$

So substituting this in $(\star)$ gives $$-yc^{-y-1}B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(-x-y)(c+t)^{-x-y-1}t^{x-1}dt$$
$$=-(x+y)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(c+t)^{x+y+1}}dt=-(x+y)c^{-y-1}B(x,y+1)$$

Thus $$B(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{y}B(x,y+1)$$